# NSOutlineView, setFloatsGroupRows: not working

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I know it should work, I can see it in sample projects, but in my sample project I can't force outline view to float group rows. The code is straightforward, everything works except that feature. Probably I'm missing something obvious.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [self.outlineView setFloatsGroupRows:YES];
}

- (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView child:(NSInteger)index ofItem:(id)item
{
    if (item == nil)
        return [@[@"1", @"2",@"3",@"4",@"5"] objectAtIndex:index];

    return nil;
}

- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView isItemExpandable:(id)item
{
    return NO;
}

- (NSInteger)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView numberOfChildrenOfItem:(id)item
{
    if (item == nil)
        return 5;

    return 0;
}

- (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn byItem:(id)item
{
    return item;
}

- (NSView *)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item
{
    NSTableCellView *tableCellView = [outlineView makeViewWithIdentifier:[tableColumn identifier] owner:self];

    return tableCellView;
}

- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView isGroupItem:(id)item
{
    if ([@[@"1", @"2",@"3",@"4",@"5"] indexOfObject:item] == 0)
        return YES;
    return NO;
}
```

**Edit** I added *NSTableView* alongside *NSOutlineView* to my project, added the same datasource and delegate methods and table view's group row flows, when outline view's one still doesn't. I'm wondering what I am missing, why outline view's group row doesn't want to fly?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. In *NSOultineView* **group rows float only over its child rows**. They don't float over other non group rows *but NSTableView* **does**. So if you have a group row without child items like in my example then it won't float.

In my opinion it's a bug or at least there shoud be an option for both cases (for at least a consistency with a table view behaviour).

Answer (score 1):

[image: Floats Group Row check box]

Make sure self.outlineView IBOutlet is connected to the NSOutlineView in the xib.

Comment: Local declaration of outlineView hides instance variable self.outlineView. Try changing self.outlineView variable's name.

Comment: no luck... I changed it to anOutlineView, it's connected, I can set other properties via this variable like backgroundColor, but setFloatsGroupRows still has no effect although it reports that it's properly set to YES. XCode 5, blank new project.

Comment: In xib, in the Attributes inspector of the outlineView, in the Table View section, there is a Float Group Rows check box. Maybe?

Comment: Mike, I found why it didn't float, see my answer below. But can you please upload a screenshot of your XCode attributes inspector. I can't find such checkbox in my version, it isn't there. Thanks for your help! Such support is always encouraging to continue to search for a solution )

Comment: I added screen of disclosed Table View section of the Outline View's Attribute inspector.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why but in my Xcode (5.0) this checkbox is missing.